# Count <a> items and display the string in an element Jquery

Tags: jquery, count, items

I have a navbar menu and I want to count the `<a>` links in each and display that number beside the parent link in the navbar item.

For instance I wanted to achieve this:
[image]

I need to do this for 'each' menu item. So I am not sure how to incorporate that into the code as I am a JS newb.

I managed to count the items but it will display all and i need the count for each item separately.

```
$('.row div').children('a').length);
```

And the next part I needed was to display 'each' number beside it's parent item. The hierachy goes like this in the code:

```
<div id="navbar-main" class="navbar-collapse">
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">
                    <span class="hide-overflow dropdown-label">
                        MENU ITEM PARENT
                        <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
                    </span>
                </a>
                <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li>
                        <div class="y-content">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <a href="link1" class="">
                                        <div class="sub-menu-container">
                                            <span class="text-bold text-primary">Li Link</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li>
                        <div class="y-content">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <a href="link2" class="">
                                        <div class="sub-menu-container">
                                            <span class="text-bold text-primary">Li Link</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I hope this is clear and understandable? Thank you so much for any help. My apologies if this has been answered similary....I did search but couldn't find exactly how to achieve it. At least in my search words.

Comment: Where the categories got printed (like Men,Women)? I am unable to find that in your code.And you have lots of un-closed tags in your input HTML

Comment: Thnaks for the reply. Oh I copied some of the source code and had to edit out some of the content so I may of removed some of the code by accident. By the way the Mens and Woman's was just a print screen I grabbed from someone who did some graphic design for a website so its not the site I was doing.

Answer (score 0):

This might help for you. There is no direct way to get the count directly as your needs, but can be achieved in couple of steps like below, Please note that this is sample code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">
  <!-- Brand -->
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>

  <!-- Links -->
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 2</a>
    </li>

    <!-- Dropdown -->
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbardrop" data-toggle="dropdown">
        Dropdown link
      </a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <!-- Dropdown 2-->
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbardrop" data-toggle="dropdown">
        Dropdown link 2
      </a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1 2</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2 2</a>

      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<br>

<div class="container">
  <h3>Navbar With Dropdown</h3>
 <div id="cnt1"> test1</div>
 <div id="cnt2"> test 2</div>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   // alert($(".dropdown-menu").length)
    var obj = $(".dropdown-menu");
   // alert($( obj ).find( "a" ).length);
    $.each( obj, function( key, value ) {
  //alert( "#cnt" +(key+1) );
  $("#cnt" +(key+1)).html($( value ).find( "a" ).length)
});

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

*Have a close look at the code below*: Here we are getting the main menu using it's `css class` and then getting menu items count under main menu and updating in `div`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   // alert($(".dropdown-menu").length)
    var obj = $(".dropdown-menu");
   // alert($( obj ).find( "a" ).length);
    $.each( obj, function( key, value ) {
  //alert( "#cnt" +(key+1) );
  $("#cnt" +(key+1)).html($( value ).find( "a" ).length)
});

});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will put it into a Codepen or Fiddle and check it out to see if I can implement it.